# query hadoop on linux mint 16

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am new in hadoop world and linux also, I started by searching the internet and I had installed virtualbox oracle latest version , then installed linux mint 16 , after that , I started installing hadoop from [this site](http://www.hadoopscreencasts.com/episodes/1)

BUT when I reach to the step of formatting namenode `hadoop namenode -format`, linux shows message `hadoop: command not found` , so can any one help , I already tried many solutions but nothing worked , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I know where you are going wrong - check that you correctly added the path's to the /home/.bashrc...something along the lines of:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

You need to ensure that HADOOP is actually held within /usr/local/hadoop.  In the case of the example you are following they used /home/hduser/hadoop.  Did you create a seperate hadoop user (hduser in the tutorial) and are you extracting it to /homr/hduser/hadoop?

Edit->

Try changing directory to the location of the executable and running it with the full path :

```
/home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: i had used a different user name ,but i had changed when i had edit the bashrc file , also when i paste the required changes in bashrc , every time from the first step it delete the first four letters from export

Comment: That can happen with linux, just ignore and type in the missing letters.  So if you run the command  "which hadoop" what does it say?

Comment: in bashrc file everything going normly , BUT when i reach to the command of " hadoop namenode -format" message shows "hadoop: command not found"

Comment: that simply means your user cannot find the command to execute, or it doesn't have permissions.  You could try the root user after a restart but that would annoy me.  I would still be inclined to check that you have successfully/correctly extracted and moved the files to the right location - if you can see them, what is the permissions on hadoop (the command you are trying to call, I am assuming it is /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop

Comment: Try changing directory to the location of the executable and running it with the full path :  /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop namenode -format

Answer (score 0):

Open new terminal to execute the `hadoop namenode -format` command.So that all environment variables set in `.bashrc` file will be available. 
One more thing, please prefer to use `root` user for executing hadoop program as I had faced some issues with folder permissions for folder like `/var`. Mostly `/var/hadoop` is being used  as temporary folder.

Comment: ok , now i closed the terminal and open it again , the message shows again "hadoop: command not found"

Comment: Have you set the variables in .bashrc file? If yes then it's not working then restart the machine.

Comment: @dalya_raad : Please upvote or accept the answer if you really helped from this.